# Unable to read application.properties from Scala Spring Boot app

Tags: scala, spring-boot

First time trying to land a Spring project in Scala but I'm finding some issues when it comes to things that seemed straightforward in Java.

This is my current context, an object and a class.

```
object Sample {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = { // launch this class via console to execute

    SpringApplication.run(classOf[SampleImpl], args: _*)

    new SampleImpl().doSomething()
  }
}
```

And then the `SampleImpl` class which contains all the logic.

```
@SpringBootApplication
class SampleImpl extends Serializable {

  @Value("${myValue}")
  val myValue: String = null

  def doSomething(): Unit = {
    print(myValue) // will always print null, should print "sample"
  }

}
```

File `application.properties` does contain the `myValue=sample` property and the file is detected since if I change the `@Value` placeholder to something not present in the file, it will complain and won't execute.

Sure has to be related with me instantiating the class and maybe creating another parallel context instead of using the true bean?

**EDIT**

Also tried with the following approach, leaving `SampleImpl` all the big stuff and `Sample` as the one running the method and params. Still no luck retrieving the value so far.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@Configuration
class SampleImpl extends Serializable {

  @BeanProperty
  @Value("${myValue}")
  var myValue: String = _

  def doSomething(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    SpringApplication.run(classOf[SampleImpl], args: _*)
    print(myValue) // will always print null, should print "sample"
  }

}
```

Comment: Does it persist when you change name of variable to something different than name of the property? Try this: 

    @Value("${myNewValue}")
    var myValue: String = null

Comment: @amorfis same thing yeah, still null as its value. Maybe Sample being a singleton because of "object" and SampleImpl being a normal class has something to do with it? I may be confusing timings between run, bean instantiation and such...

Comment: Do you have running example, on github maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Try to initialise the value with empty rather than null. something like

```
@Value("${myValue}")
val myValue: String = ""
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).